# How to catch integer(0)?

Tags: r, error-handling, integer, try-catch

Let's say we have a statement that produces `integer(0)`, e.g.

```
 a <- which(1:3 == 5)
```

What is the safest way of catching this?

Comment: I don't like the idea of treating it as an error -- in fact R's policy of not collapsing certain empty objects helps to avoid many error-recover flows, and thus leads to much cleaner code.

Comment: Don't use which.

Comment: You can test with `any`. It will return FALSE for either `which(1:3==5)` or for `1:3==5` .

Comment: @BondedDust I was trying to find `integer(0)`, which I produced using `which` as an example.

Comment: I know this is old, but could you, hadley, please outline why not to use `which`? This would be very helpful for me to avoid bad code.

Comment: Maybe because it can introduce bugs and often not necessary see discussion at the bottom of [this page](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).

Answer (score 189, accepted):

That is R's way of printing a zero length vector (an integer one), so you could test for `a` being of length 0:

```
R> length(a)
[1] 0
```

It might be worth rethinking the strategy you are using to identify *which* elements you want, but without further specific details it is difficult to suggest an alternative strategy.

Comment: It may be worth to point out to the future reader that `length(NULL) == 0` is also  `TRUE`. [user E Nord's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65706705/7941188) would be an option to test for `integer(0)` only

Answer (score 25):

If it's specifically zero length *integers*, then you want something like

```
is.integer0 <- function(x)
{
  is.integer(x) && length(x) == 0L
}
```

Check it with:

```
is.integer0(integer(0)) #TRUE
is.integer0(0L)         #FALSE
is.integer0(numeric(0)) #FALSE
```

---

You can also use `assertive` for this.

```
library(assertive)
x <- integer(0)
assert_is_integer(x)
assert_is_empty(x)
x <- 0L
assert_is_integer(x)
assert_is_empty(x)
## Error: is_empty : x has length 1, not 0.
x <- numeric(0)
assert_is_integer(x)
assert_is_empty(x)
## Error: is_integer : x is not of class 'integer'; it has class 'numeric'.
```

Comment: You could just use `!length(x)` rather than `length(x)==0`

Comment: @James.  True, but I don't think there's much of a performance issue either way, and `length(x) == 0L` reads more clearly to me.

Comment: @RichieCotton. What's up with 0L as opposed to 0?  I've tried googling it, but I'm not finding anything relevant.

Sorry about the necromancy.

Comment: @Ben: Adding an `L` suffix to a number makes R store it as an integer rather than a floating point value. See, e.g., http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Constants

Comment: Thanks! It's saved my time.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe off-topic, but R features two nice, fast and empty-aware functions for reducing logical vectors -- `any` and `all`:

```
if(any(x=='dolphin')) stop("Told you, no mammals!")
```

Comment: Yeah, would be great if there was something like `is.empty`, cuz some functions return `integer(0)` instead of `NA` or `NULL`. But for now your way is the most straightforward, and works vector-wise which is a big advantage over `length(a)`.

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by Andrie's answer, you could use `identical` and avoid any attribute problems by using the fact that it is the empty set of that class of object and combine it with an element of that class:

```
attr(a, "foo") <- "bar"

identical(1L, c(a, 1L))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Or more generally:

```
is.empty <- function(x, mode = NULL){
    if (is.null(mode)) mode <- class(x)
    identical(vector(mode, 1), c(x, vector(class(x), 1)))
}

b <- numeric(0)

is.empty(a)
#> [1] TRUE
is.empty(a,"numeric")
#> [1] FALSE
is.empty(b)
#> [1] TRUE
is.empty(b,"integer")
#> [1] FALSE
```

Comment: This is not the simplest answer, but by far the simplest and safest for beginners.

Answer (score 7):

```
if ( length(a <- which(1:3 == 5) ) ) print(a)  else print("nothing returned for 'a'") 
#[1] "nothing returned for 'a'"
```

On second thought I think any is more beautiful than `length(.)`:

```
 if ( any(a <- which(1:3 == 5) ) ) print(a)  else print("nothing returned for 'a'") 
 if ( any(a <- 1:3 == 5 ) ) print(a)  else print("nothing returned for 'a'")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily catch integer(0) with function identical(x,y)

```
x = integer(0)
identical(x, integer(0))
[1] TRUE

foo = function(x){identical(x, integer(0))}
foo(x)
[1] TRUE

foo(0)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

another option is `rlang::is_empty` (useful if you're working in the tidyverse)

The rlang namespace does not seem to be attached when attaching the tidyverse via `library(tidyverse)` - in this case you use `purrr::is_empty`, which is just imported from the `rlang` package.

By the way, `rlang::is_empty` uses [user Gavin's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6451295/7941188).

```r
rlang::is_empty(which(1:3 == 5))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

`isEmpty()` is included in the S4Vectors base package. No need to load any other packages.

```
a <- which(1:3 == 5)
isEmpty(a)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Well .. S4Vectors *is* an extra package, and one that is (as of today) not on CRAN