# Why does R return integer(0) for under-indexing but NA for over-indexing a vector?

Tags: r

If I have a vector like this:

```
x <- c(1:10)
```

and I under-index it, by asking for position 0 like this:

```
x[0]
```

I get a return type of integer(0) which I understand to be a zero length integer vector.  That is fine.  However, if I ask for an invalid index that is too high like this:

```
x[11]
```

The return is NA.

So my question is, why the difference?  Why not get a zero length vector in both cases or an NA in both cases?  Is there a reason or is this just a quirk of R?

Comment: Don't know if you have already seen this, some useful answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135325/why-do-vector-indices-in-r-start-with-1-instead-of-0

Comment: [Here the question has been asked already with some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610775/why-does-x0-return-a-zero-length-vector)

Comment: I can only construct a rationale for *both* behaviors in the context of negative indexes dropping elements: negative values greater than a vector's length do nothing (drop an element that isn't there), positive values greater than a vector's length return NA (select an unknown element, but this one is debatable as to how reasonable it is) and 0's do nothing.

Comment: ...but really this mostly feels like a "quirk" in the sense that the behavior evolved organically over a series of decisions each of which had to fit with the previous ones.

Comment: Thanks Croote.  I looked for dupes and didn't run across that one.