# What is in index 0 of an R list if they usually start with index 1?

Tags: r, list

Coming from Python I try to get deeper into the habits and design principals of R. So this is not a homework question.

It seems usual that `list()` starting with index `1` and not `0`.

```
> a = list(1,2,3)
> a[[1]]
[1] 1
```

But what is at index `0`?

```
> a[[0]]
Error in a[[0]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index <real>
> a[0]
list()
```

I know that there is a difference about `[]` and `[[]]`. I don't fully understand the difference or the design principals behind it.

Is there an PEP equivalent for R to read about design decisions?

**EDIT**: The "duplicate" question doesn't fit my question and there is also no accepted answer. The answers in my question IMHO are much better.

Comment: There is no 0 index in R. It starts from 1

Comment: See the `a[0]` in my MWE. If this is not an "index" than please answer and explain what it is.

Comment: The [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610775/why-does-x0-return-a-zero-length-vector) states that `0` indices get "ignored" which might be a bit vague. Actually it behaves as if `0` is coerced to `NULL`, try `a[c(0, 1)]`, `a[c(NULL, 1)]`, and `a[0]`, `a[NULL]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `[[]]` you are extracting the element from the list. Therefore, you will have `a[[1]] = 1`, but an error for `a[[0]]]` because there is no such element.

When you use `[]` in a list you are slicing (sub-setting) it. That is why `a[1] = [[1]] 1` and `a[0]` returns an empty element (there is no *zeroth* list).

This is made clear by checking the class of the outputs.

```
class(a[[1]]) # -> numeric
class(a[1]) # -> list
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no index 0, as you see when you use the `[[` operator, which returns the element of the list at index 0, which does not exist.

However, when you use the `[` operator a list, it returns the a list containing the object at that index. Using your example, look at the difference in what is returned using each operator.

```r
a <- list(1, 2, 3)
a[[1]] # 1
class(a[[1]]) # numeric (i.e. a vector)

a[1]
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
class(a[1]) # list
```

When you run `a[0]`, you get a list containing the object at index 0, which does not exist, i.e. an empty `list()`.