# Why not to use `which` command

Tags: r

In discusion bellow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451152/how-to-catch-integer0), there is comment:

> Don't use which.

With several upvotes.

Why is using `which` in R bad and what are alternatives/preferable approaches?

Comment: why don't you ask this question in that comment?

Comment: I would like to preferably have more answers

Comment: I don't know why not `which()`, but `-which()`, particularly on a `data.frame` can yield some unexpected results sometimes.

Comment: I suspect the comment was heavily up-voted because [hadley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley) said it, and many people seem to take what he says as gospel (which is a criticism of them, not of Hadley). Using `which` was just an example of a statement that produces `integer(0)`. Whatever example the OP gave, someone could have said, "don't use that statement", which is entirely unhelpful to answering the actual question of how to catch a zero-length vector result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be considered as a general recommendation, of course. It was just redundant in those conditions. I assume the problem was to catch the output of some function (or to use inside an if statement). If that's the case,

```
a <- which(1:3 == 5)
length(a) != 0
```

is the same as

```
b <- 1:3 == 5
any(b)
```

and the latter is clearly more elegant.

Comment: Ok. I thought it was a general recommendation and perhaps `which` can be replaced by some more efficient alternative (like `apply` instead of `for`). Thanks

Comment: @Zbynek `apply` is not more efficient than `for` in terms of performance, only in terms of clarity of code.

Comment: My experience is that `apply` is much faster when i.e. calculating sum on rows of matrix - I have just tried that and it took only about 20% of time than for loop

Comment: @Zbynek If you consider that a significant performance difference ... Using `rowSums` will speed up things by orders of magnitude in this case.