# Returning absent values without inducing integer (0)

Tags: r

I want to identify which values in one vector are present in another vector.  Sometimes, in my application, none of the values of the first vector are present; in such cases I would like NA.  My current approach returns integer(0) when this occurs:

```
l <- 1:3
m <- 2:5
n <- 4:6
l[l %in% m]
```

1] 2 3

```
l[l %in% n]
```

integer(0)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451152/how-to-catch-integer0) discusses how to capture integer(0) using `length`, but is there a way to avoid integer(0) in the first place, and do this operation in just one step?  Answers to the previous question suggest that `any` could be used but I fail to see how that would work in this example.

Comment: `i <- l %in% n; if (any(i)) l[i] else NA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch the `integer(0)` with a custom function:

```
l <- 1:3
m <- 2:5
n <- 4:6

returnsafe <- function(a, b) {
    result <- a[a %in% b]
    if(is.integer(result) && length(result) == 0L) {
        return(NA)
    } else {
        return(result)
    }
}


> returnsafe(l, n)
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
l[match(l, n)]

[1] NA NA NA
```

Or:

```
any(l[match(l, n)])

[1] NA
```